# Pasar de una página a otra desde Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo una app en WP con varias interfaces de usuario pero no se como puedo pasar de una a la otra. En **ASP.NET** tenia algo como esto:

```
Response.Redirect("~URL/paginilla.aspx");
```

Supongo que no es la gran cosa, pero es diferente ¿cierto?

Comment: que versiónde WP trabajas?

Comment: Estas programando com xaml o WinJS ?

Comment: implementas algun patron como ser MVVM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Oswa tienes dos formas de hacerlo, con parámetros o sin parámetros:

```
//Sin parámetros:

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Panorama.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

//Con parámetros:

//Desde la pagina que envía
string Variable = "YourValue";

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Panorama.xaml?Var="+Variable, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

//Desde la pagina que recibe

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    string VariableReceived = "";

    if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("Var", out VariableReceived))
    {
       //Here you have the value
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahorita tuve la necesidad de pasar parámetro. No entiendo por que el base.OnNavigatedTo(e) pero esta trabajando, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para redireccionar a una página debes hacerlo así:

En `WP 8` o anterior:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/App/Example.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

En `WP 8.1` con parámetros:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Example), param);
```

o sin parámetros:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Example));
```

Para este último puedes revisar la documentación acá : [Navegación entre páginas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ejemplos de la documentacion del msdn ayudaria a entender como navegar entre las paginas

[How to perform page navigation on Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Como observaras alli usa

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

para redireccionar a otra ventana

Tambien recomiendo los video de Channel9

[Building Apps for Windows Phone 8.1: (03) Page Navigation and Data Binding in Windows Runtime Apps](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/03)